# Meaning of the equation of graphical model

Tags: mobile-robot, control, robotic-arm, motion-planning

The paper [*Topology-based Representations for Motion Planning
and Generalisation in Dynamic Environments with
Interactions*](https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/mlr/papers/13-ivan-IJRR.pdf) by Ivan
et.al., says on page 10 that the Approximate Inference Control (AICO) framework translates the robot dynamics to the graphical model by the following equation:

[image]

What does p(x0:T,u0:T) mean? I feel that p means 'prior of' some uncertain quantity, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Maybe you should be more specific in your question. $p(x_{0:T},u_{0:T})$ normally means the joint probability distribution of all states and control inputs.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a prior. It is the posterior of trajectory and controls. Basically that equation gives you the motion model of the robot similar to the motion models described in Sebastian Thrun's Probabilistic Robotics. $x_{0:t}$ is a set of poses i.e., trajectory and $u_{0:t}$ is a set of controls, i.e., Motor commands for the joints. The posterior here provides a likelihood estimate of the robot's pose after a control command. From what I understand after skimming through the rather obscure paper and another paper [Robot Trajectory Optimization using Approximate Inference](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~todorov/courses/amath579/reading/Toussaint.pdf) that the LHS is used to compute a likelihood for the next pose, $x_{t+1}$ if a control action $u_t$ is chosen with the knowledge of $x_t$. The LHS can be viewed as described in the Background section below. From the latter paper, the estimation of state $x_{t+1}$ requires some confidence on the knowledge of current state $x_t$ which is given by the covariance matrix $A$ and mean $a$.

**Background:**

$p(x_{0:t},u_{0:t})$ is called a state transition probability, it can also be written as $p(x_{t}|x_{0:t-1}, u_{0:t})$ since it can be assumed that $x_t$ is a complete state or here just the pose of the robot, i.e. it is a summary of all that happened in the past poses after executing commands in the set $u_{1:t}$. What this results in is that $x_t$ is conditional stochastically on $x_{t-1}$ and can be estimated by executing the command $u_t$. Which is what the motion model does for you and it is shown as $p(x_t|u_t, x_{t-1})$. It says that the state $x_t$ depends on $u_t$ and can be computed as long as $x_{t-1}$ is known.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Tvaṣṭā. But what does posterior trajectory and control mean?

Comment: I have edited the answer to add what the posterior means.

Comment: If it means likelihood estimate of robot's pose "**given**" a control command, then why it is not written like this: p(x0:t | u0:t)? I mean why it is not written in terms of conditional probability?@Tvaṣṭā

Comment: @vacky my wrong choice of words - the posterior estimates the likelihood after a control command is given. It makes use of the command to construct an estimate of what its pose is as a result of the command.